# How to Dynamically Assign DropDown Value in MVC 5 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Model that contains basic address information:

```
public class AddressModel()
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

When passing it into a form in my View, I am placing the values into a textbox, except for the State, which is a dropdown box that is hardcoded to contain the states in America:

```
<form>
   <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                   <!-- First Name -->
                   <label for="first_name_id" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name_id" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="@Html.ViewData.Model.Patient.FirstName.First().ToString().ToUpper()@Html.ViewData.Model.FirstName.Substring(1).ToLower()">
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <!-- Last Name -->
                       <label for="last_name_id" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name_id" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="@Html.ViewData.Model.Patient.LastName.First().ToString().ToUpper()@Html.ViewData.Model.LastName.Substring(1).ToLower()">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- Street 1 -->
                                <label for="street1_id" class="control-label">Street Address 1</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street1_id" name="street1" placeholder="" value="@Html.ViewData.Patient.BillingAddress1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- Street 2 -->
                                <label for="street2_id" class="control-label">Street Address 2</label>
                                <input style="margin-left: 0px" type="text" class="form-control" id="street2_id" name="street2" placeholder="Apartment, Suite, etc." value="@Html.ViewData.Patient.BillingAddress2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- City-->
                                <label for="city_id" class="control-label">City</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city_id" name="city" placeholder="" value="@Html.ViewData.Model.BillingCity">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- State Dropdown-->
                                <label for="state_id" class="control-label">State</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="state_id">
                                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- Zip Code-->
                                <label for="zip_id" class="control-label">Zip Code</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip_id" name="zip" placeholder="" value="@Html.ViewData.Model.BillingZip">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Is there a way to assign the value/option of the drop down in this current format?  I can't seem to figure out a way to set the value this way.  Do I use the HTML Helper Method for dropdowns, given the list of states?  Currently the Value is always set to Alabama.

Comment: Why in the world are you generating all that html manually (which will ever give you correct 2 way model binding or validation) instead of using the `HtmlHelper` methods (which will bind correctly and in far less code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Option element has a "Selected" property, like

```
<option value="CA" selected="selected">California</option>
```

You could also set in javascript like

```
document.getElementById("state_id").value = "CA";
```

I am not sure what dictates what the default value needs to be. Is there an event, like changing the text in another textbox, or a value available, like a CustomerID, that determines which Option element should be defaulted? Let me know...

Comment: So, there is a search for, say, customerID.  Our database has a State field for each Customer and I want the dropdown box to have the value of that state when the Customer UI is loaded.  So, Maybe a javascript onLoad  function could help with that assignment?

Comment: yes, something like 

window.onload = function(){
        // Put your logic here, reference the model property, set select value.        
    }

You may want to add the State value (i.e. 'CA') to your model so that it is easily referencable

Comment: I thought about making it a list rather than hard coded options in the field, but I could always dynamically add the list as a drop down menu with the HTML or something... thank you for your guidance, I needed some sort of direction.